# How can I get the "uptime" of asp.net site hosted in IIS10, from e.g. default.aspx.cs?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm hosting an asp.net site on my IIS10 server.  I want to get the SITE uptime (or, from what I gather is the equivalent: the APPPOOL uptime).   I already know how to obtain the Client Process uptime, and the Server uptime.  I thought I could use Microsoft.Web.Administration ServerManager, locate the Site of interest, attributes etc. but I don't find any "time" values anywhere in that. (I may not have exhausted the search, but I've exhausted myself! :) ).   Does IIS have a directly accessible API?  I've looked at a lot of "answers" to this, but so many seem to point to "external" 3rd party "tools" etc., which I am Not interested in.  I need to pull this info from code-behind one of my site's pages.  Thanks for any insights!

Comment: IIS is a service starting with Windows kernel, and all sites become active that early to take incoming requests. Thus, I don't think the "uptime" of a site you are looking for is any different from Windows Server uptime. What exactly do you want?

Comment: The uptime of the Server is NOT the same as the uptime of any of a number of Sites that may be hosted by one instance of IIS.   For example, I can go into IIS Manager and STOP a particular Site; at the moment it may be Restarted, it's uptime will be nearly 0, while the uptime of the Server might be measured in Months.  The uptime of a specific SITE is what I want to obtain.

Comment: As you found out, there is nothing to track that. Shutting down a site is so rare  on production machines (ever rare if adding maintenance). Uptime of the server itself is rarely “measured in months” if you know what is patch Tuesday. Anyway, I won’t comment any more since you don’t seem to be interested in that.

Comment: Unfortunately, IIS has no API available for direct access to get the uptime of a specific site.

Answer (score 0):

Got back to this after a while; found simple solution:
In the Global.asax.cs, I added a static DateTime variable _siteStartTime.  Then I added a property to calculate and return the site's uptime:

```
public static string SiteUpTime
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - _siteStartTime;
            return (string.Format("{0}d {1}:{2}:{3}",
                ts.Days, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds));
        }
    }
```

That's all there is to it. Bam!